# Android studio Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.2.0-4818971

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently updated my android studio to 3.2 and now i have this error on build :

```
Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.2.0-4818971.
Searched in the following locations:
file:/C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971.pom
file:/C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar
file:/C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971.pom
file:/C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar
file:/C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971.pom
file:/C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar
file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971.pom
file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971.pom
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar
https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971.pom
https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar
https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971.pom
https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.0-4818971/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar
Required by:
    project :android
```

What is this ? and how to fix it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build errors after Android Studio 3.2.1 upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52790020/build-errors-after-android-studio-3-2-1-upgrade)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `google()` do your build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following solved my issue under jar folder there are 3 folders, one of the folder consists of the aapt2.exe in it. I copied that file to other folder where I am getting error.

ex: path of jar: `C:\Users\umabhavania\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar`

error path: `C:\Users\umabhavania\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\a57a698502c21bfe8cfc3ed6eb102b39\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows`

copied `aapt2.exe` file from `57f15fb82085ec9389484ff7e041344f folder to a57a698502c21bfe8cfc3ed6eb102b39`

Hope this helps..

Comment: This probably means your cache was corrupted. If you deleted C:\Users\umabhavania\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2* it also should have worked.