# How to solve Specified AAPT2 executable does not exist on Android Studio 3.2

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, aapt2

I've an issue with Android Studio. I'm trying to use it on Windows but I've trouble during the project's build process.

First, notice Android Studio is installed on my secondary HDD.

When I try to build/run my project I get this error:

```
Specified AAPT2 executable does not exist:
C:\Users\Rémi\\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar\35960bdffa2420a45dff6ec260c07fa9\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe
```

And indeed there is no `aapt2.exe` here.

But I've found this .exe here:

```
H:\Logiciels\AndroidStudioSDK\build-tools\28.0.2\aapt2.exe
```

and a previous version here:

```
H:\Logiciels\AndroidStudioSDK\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt2.exe
```

I've tried to fix this issue by changing the build tools version by setting ***File > Project structure > Modules > App > Build Tools Version***. This option was empty and I chose 28.0.2 but that doesn't change anything.

Thanks for reading.

P.S.: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52542109/android-studio-could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildaapt23-2-0-4818971) is not the same. My error is different and I have `google()` in my Grable file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android studio Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.2.0-4818971](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52542109/android-studio-could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildaapt23-2-0-4818971)

Answer (score 9):

I solved it by deleting the directory under which it expected the aapt2 executable, e.g. `C:\Users\support\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\4c1f5b7dca1d5d378360be7f3fd9726a\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows` and then did a clean in Android Studio `Build`>`Clean Project`.

Afterwards it appears to have downloaded this again, with the missing executable, and now works perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. I resolved it by opening my file browser and navigating to this folder
`C:\Users\(My User Name)\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar`

Opening this folder and viewing its contents, I deleted the folder labeled `81c3666e327fa931c773a52e6cb0b3b7` which for you would be `35960bdffa2420a45dff6ec260c07fa9`.

After this I went back to Android Studio and clicked the ***Build*** menu, and used the ***Clean Project*** option, followed by the ***Rebuild Project*** option.

I no longer get this error, or all the debug errors that say the Java package "R" did not exist.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @NarwhalGod, please always be mindful to use formatting when posting. This will make your posts more readable.

Comment: Many people got this error in Flutter also, it also specifies AndroidX compatibility issues, in reality only this was the issue. This method worked after Googling for hours, thankyou :)

Answer (score 1):

Following solved my issue
under jar folder there are 3 folders, one of the folder consists of the aapt2.exe in it.
I copied that file to other folder where I am getting error.

ex:
path of jar: `C:\Users\umabhavania\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar`

error path: `C:\Users\umabhavania\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\a57a698502c21bfe8cfc3ed6eb102b39\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows`

copied aapt2.exe file from `57f15fb82085ec9389484ff7e041344f` folder to `a57a698502c21bfe8cfc3ed6eb102b39`

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by removing that folder

Go to that path -> Delete

Ex: C:\Users\Rémi.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar\35960bdffa2420a45dff6ec260c07fa9\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe

In this go to "C:\Users\Rémi.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar\" and delete 35960bdffa2420a45dff6ec260c07fa9

Clean Project and Build

Answer (score 1):

Just chnage the gradle version in your build.gradle file in android folder.
For example mine was 4.1.0, changed it to 4.1.1

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1- enter to the file like

`C:\Users\4khalil\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.3.2-5309881-windows.jar\6abc6a09978228d11497e7ca9c3de2c9\aapt2-3.3.2-5309881-windows`

then if you find `aapt2.exe.dat`, delete the extension `.dat` to be `aapt2.exe` 
 and the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'invalidate cache and restart'.

In Android Studio, go to File menu -> click Invalidate Caches/Restart.

Answer (score -2):

just copy paste this file aap2.exe get it from a friend or somewhere at this location and paste it on the same folder found in yours in .gradle C:\Users\Dina.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\8735df2342ae4ae127451389faa5e1f1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\
then build and then the build will complete successful.
I didn't know how to attach the file in my answer I am new to stack overflow.

Comment: You can't attach files here on Stack Overflow. You can provide a link to an official source though.

Comment: Please don't do this! This is very dangerous (since if you download it from an unknown source it might be malware!), instead you should delete the gradle cache folder and let gradle re-download the file for you.