# Android: specified AAPT2 executable does not exist: after adding kotlin support while creating app

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-studio-3.2, aapt2

Hi I have updated android studio to 3.2.1 recently, It is working fine with existing projects(java).
Issue is when I am trying to create an new project (checking Include kotlin Support) then it is showing the following error

**build failed:**

```
Specified AAPT2 executable does not exist: C:\Users\umabhavania\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\e602e2dea30bbf2cabd801a8d81b8cdd\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe
```

I have searched for this and also tried following

deleting the directory under which it expected the aapt2 executable
[As mentioned in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52850928/6333830)

but found no difference, Please help me.

Comment: have you applied `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` in your app build.gradle.

Comment: using kotlin or not has no effect on the aapt2 executable. What's possible is that your cache got corrupted or for some reason your antivirus is blocking aapt2. Delete the whole C:\Users\umabhavania\.gradle directory and see if that helps

Comment: thanks Izabela Orlowska, Solved this issue with below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following solved my issue under jar folder there are 3 folders, one of the folder consists of the **aapt2.exe** in it. I copied that file to other folder where I am getting error.

ex: path of jar: `C:\Users\umabhavania\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar`

error path:

```
C:\Users\umabhavania\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\a57a698502c21bfe8cfc3ed6eb102b39\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows
```

copied `aapt2.exe` file from `57f15fb82085ec9389484ff7e041344f` folder to `a57a698502c21bfe8cfc3ed6eb102b39`

Hope this helps..