# Must supply one of aapt2 from maven or custom location

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I am trying to run my flutter app but I got some error.

```
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
    > Specified AAPT2 executable does not exist: C:\Users\john\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a406eb4ba72ff395bc6c8b1db90b3b1f\aapt2-3.5.0-5435860-windows\aapt2.exe. 
    Must supply one of aapt2 from maven or custom location.
        
    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    
    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

This is my buildscript

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Last time I can run my flutter app but now I don't know what happened. I hope you can help me. TIA

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using? You should be on AS 4.0 with a corresponding Android Gradle Plugin version (4.0)

Comment: Delete the .gradle file, Android Studio should create it again

Comment: @user3425867 I already did that but still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the solution to my problem.

I changed the dependencies classpath in my buildsript

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Into

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Now it's working!

Answer (score 0):

click in file and Invalidate caches

[image]

if not solved verify you resources and delete document mipmap-anydpi-v26

[image]

where click in Build and clean project

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try running `flutter clean` on Android Studio's terminal or just selecting the option on the Flutter menu at the top:

[image: Flutter clean tools]

If this doesn't work, take a look at this question: [How to solve Specified AAPT2 executable does not exist on Android Studio 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52545740)

Comment: Could you create a new project from scratch, copy your code there and try to rebuild it?

Comment: I already did that. I also create new flutter project but still having the same problem

Comment: Have you copied just the code? Can you compile a simple counter demo?